# Getting User input in bash script

Tags: bash, unix, user-input

Getting Input From stdin

The command "read varname" will read a value from stdin and assign it to a variable called varname. If the variable does not yet exist, it will be created.

Note that the option "-n" can be used with echo to cause it to not output a newline character. (This is nice when printing user prompts, so the user can enter a response on the same line as the prompt).

Create a copy of countdown.sh called countdown2.sh and change it such that it prompts the user for a starting value, and counts down from there.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a number 

while [$i -gt 0 };
do
echo $i
((i--))
sleep 1

done
echo GO!
```

It is not working and I know it is probley a simple mistake but I also know that I am not using what my lab is asking for. Please help.

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: Try pasting your script into [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) and fixing the mistakes it calls out.

Comment: Also you are referencing a variable `$i` that you never define anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
while [$i -gt 0 };
```

You make two mistakes (at least)

1. you use two different brackets.
2. You did not add space after `[`
3. It is good practice to surround variables with double quotes

So you line should be:

```
while [ "$i" -gt 0 ]
```

You should also edit you first line to become:

```
read -p "Enter a number:" i
```

Comment: So how do I do a command that reads varname and is assigned to a variable called varname

Comment: @Kraken, check my edited answer

Comment: You're missing a closing quote in your edit. (And on the nitpicky side, `read` should always be invoked with `-r` to avoid backslash mangling - so `read -rp "Enter a number: " i`)

Comment: @tjm3772, corrected :) (nonresposive keyboard :) )

Comment: @Kraken, I add in the answer how to change it

Comment: how would I change the initial value into a command-line argument

Comment: @Kraken, you do not need to create initial value. But you can assign (if you have command line argument) with `i=$1`

Comment: #!/bin/bash

read -rp "Enter a number: " i

while [ "$i" -gt 0 ];
do
echo $i
((i--))
sleep 1

done
echo GO!                                                                                                                           This is what you suggested and I did it. The only problem is that for my lab I am suppose to be using the varName method and then after I do that I am suppose to change it so that it accepts the initial value as a command-line argument

Comment: I am still learning how to do this. This is my first call in linux and this is only my 5 lab

Comment: reread your material. If they have asked you to do something, it is most likely that they have demonstrated that feature (-;. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I have reread the material and my labs are manly made up of go on line and google till you find the answer.

Comment: reread the section about the numbered env vars, i.e. `$0, $1, $....n` . Good luck.